# Static cast from negative int to uint

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following check where it is possible for the condition to underflow.

```
uint16_t lo; 
uint16_t input; 
...
uint16_t newLo = std::clamp(lo-input, 0, lo);
```

This causes a compiler error due to the promotion of types to int when doing the calculation ("Compiler error" is caused by gcc flags: `-Wall -Werror`).

Is it safe to statically cast the value of the calculation if it can cause an underflow?

```
uint16_t lo; 
uint16_t input; 
...
uint16_t compVal = static_cast<uint16_t>(lo-input);
uint16_t newLo = std::clamp(compVal, 0, lo);
```

Comment: It's safe in the sense that underflow for unsigned types is not Undefined Behavior.  But whether or not it makes sense to allow underflow completely depends on the context.

Comment: Also note that since the arguments are unsigned, `std::clamp(compVal, 0, lo)` is equivalent to `std::min(compVal, lo)` (i.e. the lower bound of 0 will never apply)

Comment: How about `std::clamp(lo - input, 0, +lo);` or `std::clamp<uint16_t>(lo - input, 0, lo);`

Comment: The output of `clamp` in this case will always be positive, so how would you get underflow?

Comment: can't you just work with int and cast the final result to uint?

Comment: @MarkRansom The underflow happens here `uint16_t compVal = static_cast<uint16_t>(lo-input);` when `input > lo`

Comment: Wouldn't the subtraction `lo-input` be already performed on values up-cast to `int`?  If not, you can force it: `static_cast<int>(lo)-static_cast<int>(input)`.  Since `int` will be able to contain all `uint16_t` values there won't be any underflow, and then as I said `clamp` will restrict the range of values back to something that can be held by `uint16_t`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, by the standard, `int` can have 16 bits, too.

Comment: Re: "This causes a compiler error" -- if your compiler refuses to compile that code it does not conform to the language definition.

Comment: @Evg yes, technically you're right.  I haven't seen one since I stopped programming for the Z80.

Comment: @PeteBecker The project is compiled with all `-Wall -Werror` I have updated the question to reflect this nuance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `std::clamp` with argument `0` as second argument then apparently you are expecting possible negative value.

```cpp
uint16_t compVal = static_cast<uint16_t>(lo-input);
uint16_t newLo = std::clamp(compVal, {}, lo);
```

This fixes compile error, but hides actual problem when `lo < input`.
Actual behavior will wrap around actual value and `compVal` will always be greater or equal zero. I do not think this is what you are expecting.

The most resolvable approach was proposed by @Ayxan in a comment:

```cpp
uint16_t newLo = std::clamp(lo - input, 0, +lo);
```

Here all arguments of `clamp` are `int` type, then result is silently converted to `uint16_t` and you have a guarantee that there is no integer overflow since result will fit into destination type.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8asds3)

Comment: I think 0 is interpreted as an int, shouldn't that 0 be a uint16_t? If not, I get a template deduction error.

Comment: Also, if input > lo, are you returning 0 or lo? I think the expected answer here is 0, unless I understood bad the question.

Comment: @mfnx yes you are right I missed that :). Fixed this by using `{}`.

Comment: If `input > lo` his solution will most probably return `lo` not `0`, `Ayxan` proposal will return expected `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really need the type `uint16_t` and you really want to use `std::clamp`:

```
// int can hold any uint16_t
uint16_t newLo = std::clamp(static_cast<int>(lo) - static_cast<int>(input),
                            0,
                            static_cast<int>(lo));
```

You could also simply do this:

```
uint16_t newLo = input < lo ? lo - input : 0;
```

The above is assuming that the behaviour you expect (which is not entirely clear from the question) is the same as if your `uint16_t` were a `int`, that is: 3 - 5 returns 0.

As an additional note, I would avoid subtracting a value from an `uint` whenever possible.